Osmotic pressure in a communicating vessel
Let's consider a hollow U tube, at the base of it is a semi-penetrable membrane separating the two sides. On each side is poured in 100ml of, for example, NaCl with different concentration (aM and bM)
I want to calculate the height difference between the two sides at equilibrium.
I assume that at equilibrium, osmotic pressure is equal, so C1 * RT = C2 * RT or the concentration of NaCl is equal
so a100/V1 = b100/V2 (V1 and V2 are the volume of liquid in each side at equilibrium)
And given that V1 + V2 = 200 mL, V1 and V2 can be calculated
Then the height difference will be (v2 - v1)/ (Area of tube)
Is my method correct? Any help is appreciated!

If there is height difference then osmotic pressures cannot be the same.

can you be more specific? if the concentration is similar, then what causes the difference? is it fluid pressure?

At the equilibrium, the difference of hydrostatic pressures is equal to the difference of osmotic pressures.
